# How to hide a particular item of a spinner for different activities?

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner which is being called by various activities simultaneously.But i want to hide some items of that spinner according to activity which calls it. How to do that?

i have that method ready

if(Call by Activity 1)
{ 
Code}

if(Call by Activity 2)
{ 
Code}

I am just aware about setvisibility method which hides entire spinner but here i want to hide some of its items.

Comment: Updating the list you pass to the Adapter of the Spinner should be a better idea. I don't understand the part: 'I have a spinner which is being called by various activities simultaneously' because this should not be possible. if you intended that you are using the same xml layout for multiple activities you can go as i said

Comment: i have a activity say name cannonActivity which contains 6 spinners. When activity 1 calls it I hide 1 spinner from it by checking in if condition at the beginning of cannonsAcitivity . For eg if(activity==1){sp1.setvisibility(view.gone); similarly i want to hide some of the items of one of the 5 spinners visible. @MatPag

Comment: activity 1 starts cannonActivity with an Intent right? And are you using the same XML layout for both activities?

Comment: exactly @MatPag i am successful in hiding the entire spinner for particular activity but i want to hide items from the spinner left. and yes using same xml.